# UIPasteboard containing images AND text- pasting into Mail

Tags: ios, email, clipboard, copy-paste, uipasteboard

Since iOS8, the behaviour of Mail with the pasteboard seems to have changed.

I am trying to copy both images and text from my app, in a format that I can paste into the Mail app.

A UIPasteboard containing both images and text will only paste the images into Mail. A pasteboard containing one or the other works fine.

I create a dictionary for each text and image element, add them all to an array, then set pasteboard.items to the array. This method has worked for a year or two.

My guess would be that Mail now takes the "best" data in the pasteboard, and assumes that the text was included only as a fallback (such as a text description).

Has anyone else observed the same problem, and is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to add some text and a image to the UIPasteboard a few days ago, I found that ONLY the image was added to the UIPasteboard.

```
UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string = text
UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().image = image
```

I use the code above then check `UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string` was `nil`, I firmly sure that my text wasn't nil. So, this may be a bug.